# WooCommerce/Authorize.net interface problem

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

Our WooCommerce site was working until recently, but now we have the following problem.

Everything is working in the order process until the customer gets to the checkout page and clicks on "Place Order." The next screen that comes up displays the order number, date, total and payment method - Authorize.net.  Finally, there is a line which says "Thank you for your order, please click the button below to pay with Authorize.net." However, there is no button showing up anywhere.

Any idea what might be happening? Sorry, I don't know exactly how we interface with Authorize.net.

Comment: You're most likely using a plugin for the authorize.net gateway.  you should reach out to the plugin developer for help with this.

Comment: you should also check with woothemes and your theme developer.  You could do a quick test by changing themes and see if it's the problem.